# Is Django inherently more difficult to host than RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, hosting

I know there are a lot of existing questions on Django hosting etc but my question is whether there is a technical reason why RoR hosts are easier to get by than Django hosts. Is there something in the technology itself or the architecture that makes it more of a hassle for providers to host and maintain?

It's both seemingly easier to find better free hosts for RoR than for Django (10mb from alwaysdata really doesn't allow for a lot and App Engine isn't a vanilla Django) and easier to find decent RoR hosts for 2$/month packed with features than for Django.

Is the reason technical or just because of market share/timing?

Thanks,
Xiao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's face it, free hosts are nowhere near good, and nor are very cheap ones.
If you want a decent host, you will have to pay a decent amount.

On the other hand, rails is nearly 1 year older than django, and started to popularize way earlier than django did. Also, php being older and popularized earlier, it seems a good reason for rails to be more popular with hosts than django.

Comment: Heroku is free (if you just need a test deployment) and nowadays there is not something like that for django (not yet at least)

Comment: There's [Djangy](https://www.djangy.com/) which is effectively a Heroku clone, which includes a first instance for free. However I think they're still in private beta.

Comment: @theTRON Djangy is dead and similar projects (eg. Gondor, ep.io, dotcloud.com ...) does not offer free dev instances or are still in beta. Heroku it's in production since years :)

Answer (score 0):

Django it is not more difficult to host than RoR.

IMHO this offering delta is there mostly because of the market share the RoR has compared to Django.

If it is true that rails is older than Django, it's also true that Python is older (and used by more people) than Ruby.

Also a technology like WSGI that makes things easier for web applications was already there when something similar came out for Ruby (Rack).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's less timing and more community push, myself. There is an extremely active and vocal community behind Rails. Just go down to your local bookstore and take a look at the books there. You'll probably find 5x the amount of Rails books that you will find over Django. As it is said, the squeeky wheel gets greased. There is a strong vocal minority of Rails users, and that means that people will cater to them on shared hosts, because otherwise they'll have to listen to a lot of requests that keep asking for it.

Not to say that time-in-market doesn't have something to do with it, I just find that the community behind any given technology has a lot to do with it's level of adoption in different business models.

Also, any host that hosts Ruby apps can host just about any of the major frameworks, as long as they are Rack compatible. So for having to deal with Rails, they usually get support for Sinatra, Ramaze, etc, for free. Instead of just supporting Django.

Comment: As Ruby uses Rack, Python uses WSGI (that's also older) so I don't see any difference between the two.

Comment: @Tommaso Barbugli- The only reason I consider that a reason is because Rack has got a vocal community. Yes, you're right. And in fact it works (to some degree) with Passenger. I haven't done a lot of testing with it, but I know that it works that way on one of the hosts that I have.